# PLSQL script for exporting data into .csv format its working fine. I am looking for one file in which all data will come in proper format

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper, sql-scripts

I have one PL-SQL script for exporting data into .csv format its working fine. I am looking for one .csv file(I can open in excel format) in which all data will come in proper format.

In existing code it asks for start, end date and table name. but it will create one file for one table name. I want same file having table data of which user gave as input.

**Working PLSQL Script:**

---

```
DECLARE
startdate DATE := to_date('&Enter_Start_Date', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
enddate DATE   := to_date('&Enter_End_Date', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
v_file            UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
 CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT TO_CHAR(createstampa2,'YYYY-MM-DD') as createdate,
    COUNT(createstampa2) as objectcount
    FROM &table_name lc -- It will prompt me for entering single table name only I want to give multiple table names here
    WHERE ( lc.createStampA2   >= to_date(startdate)
    AND lc.createStampA2        < to_date(enddate) )
    HAVING COUNT(createstampa2) > 1
    GROUP BY TO_CHAR(createstampa2,'YYYY-MM-DD')
    ORDER BY COUNT(createstampa2) DESC; 

BEGIN

    v_file := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(location     => 'XSDDIR',
                             filename     => 'GIVE_FILE_NAME_HERE'||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD_MM_YYYY')||'.csv',
                             open_mode    => 'w',
                             max_linesize =>10000);

    FOR rec IN c1 LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('createdate::'||rec.createdate);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('objectcount::'||rec.objectcount);

        UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_file,
                          rec.createdate    || ',' ||
                          rec.objectcount);
    END LOOP;

    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_file);

EXCEPTION      
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_file);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error Occured::'||SQLERRM);
    RETURN;
END;
```

---

**Expected output should be in below format(.csv file):**

[image]

Comment: I am looking like whenever I will get third prompt for table name then I need that value and want to put in excel something like  
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Entered table name'); and then data of particular table again 1 line will skip and for another table data it will append. I have shown expected ouput in above screenshot. Can this possible ?

Answer (score 4):

Open the file in append mode:

> v_file := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(location     => 'XSDDIR',
>                                filename     => 'GIVE_FILE_NAME_HERE'||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD_MM_YYYY')||'.csv',
>                                open_mode    => **'a'**,
>                                max_linesize =>10000);

Comment: Thanks for the reply btpys, I am looking for like when I will third prompt for table name then I need that value and want to put in excel like: DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Entered table name');  and then data of particular table again 1 line will skip and for another table data it will append.  'a' is working with me thanks for your help.

Comment: Dunno if I understood correctly... you can use this: dbms_output.put_line ('Table ' || '&table_name');

Answer (score 1):

Reading the comments inline (between codes), I could understand that you want to pass on **multiple tablename** as input parameter and those passed input **table** should be used in query to fetch records and write it csv file.

**Note this query is wrong:**  --<<<<<<<< `Having` clause comes after `Group by`

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(createstampa2,'YYYY-MM-DD') as createdate,
    COUNT(createstampa2) as objectcount
    FROM &table_name lc -- It will prompt me for entering single table name only I want to give multiple table names here
    WHERE ( lc.createStampA2   >= to_date(startdate)
    AND lc.createStampA2        < to_date(enddate) )
    HAVING COUNT(createstampa2) > 1   ---<<<<<<<< Having clause comes after Group by
    GROUP BY TO_CHAR(createstampa2,'YYYY-MM-DD')
    ORDER BY COUNT(createstampa2) DESC;
```

You can do that using Oracle `PLSQL` tables and collections as shown below:
Read the comments inline to understand more.

```
 DECLARE
    startdate DATE := to_date('&Enter_Start_Date', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
    enddate DATE   := to_date('&Enter_End_Date', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
    v_file            UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
    --passing multiple tablenames at runtime
    var   sys.odcivarchar2list := sys.odcivarchar2list(&table1, &table2, &table3); 

    -- Type of date and count to hold records
    Type var_dt is table of DATE;
    v_date  var_dt:=var_dt();

    Type var_cnt is table of number;
    v_cnt   var_cnt;

    v_sql   varchar2(500);
BEGIN
    v_file := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(location     => 'XSDDIR',
                             filename     => 'GIVE_FILE_NAME_HERE'||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD_MM_YYYY')||'.csv',
                             open_mode    => 'w',
                             max_linesize =>10000); 

    FOR i IN ( SELECT column_value col FROM TABLE ( var )) 
    LOOP            
    --Passing tablnames 
    v_sql:=
     q'[SELECT TO_DATE(createstampa2,'YYYY-MM-DD') as createdate,
              COUNT(createstampa2) as objectcount
       FROM  ]' || i.col ||
     q'[  WHERE 
       createstampa2       >= :startdate 
       AND   createstampa2 < :enddate
       group by TO_DATE(createstampa2,'YYYY-MM-DD') 
       HAVING  COUNT(createstampa2) > 1
       order by count ( createstampa2 ) desc]';                

        Execute immediate v_sql bulk collect into v_date , v_cnt using startdate,enddate;  

       FOR rec IN 1..v_date.count
       LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('createdate::'||v_date(rec));
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('objectcount::'||v_cnt(rec));

        UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_file,v_date(rec) || ',' ||v_cnt(rec));           

        END LOOP;

    END LOOP;

    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_file);

EXCEPTION      
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_file);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error Occured::'||SQLERRM);
    RETURN;
END;
```

**Demo:**

```
**Code:**

DECLARE
    startdate DATE := to_date('&Enter_Start_Date', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
    enddate DATE   := to_date('&Enter_End_Date', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
    v_file            UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
    --passing multiple tablenames at runtime
    var   sys.odcivarchar2list := sys.odcivarchar2list(&table1, &table2, &table3); 

    -- Type of date and count to hold records
    Type var_dt is table of DATE;
    v_date  var_dt:=var_dt();

    Type var_cnt is table of number;
    v_cnt   var_cnt;

    v_sql   varchar2(500);
BEGIN
   /* v_file := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(location     => 'XSDDIR',
                             filename     => 'GIVE_FILE_NAME_HERE'||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD_MM_YYYY')||'.csv',
                             open_mode    => 'w',
                             max_linesize =>10000); */

    FOR i IN ( SELECT column_value col FROM TABLE ( var )) 
    LOOP            
    --Passing tablnames 
    v_sql:=
     q'[SELECT TO_DATE(createstampa2,'YYYY-MM-DD') as createdate,
              COUNT(createstampa2) as objectcount
       FROM  ]' || i.col ||
     q'[  WHERE 
       createstampa2       >= :startdate 
       AND   createstampa2 < :enddate
       group by TO_DATE(createstampa2,'YYYY-MM-DD') 
       HAVING  COUNT(createstampa2) > 1
       order by count ( createstampa2 ) desc]';              

       Execute immediate v_sql bulk collect into v_date , v_cnt using startdate,enddate;  

       FOR rec IN 1..v_date.count
       LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('createdate::'||v_date(rec));
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('objectcount::'||v_cnt(rec));

       -- UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_file,v_date(rec) || ',' ||v_cnt(rec));           

        END LOOP;

    END LOOP;

    --UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_file);

EXCEPTION      
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    --UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_file);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error Occured::'||SQLERRM);
    RETURN;
END;
```

This is to explain the concept. I am not wrting anything to file so in demo you would find the code `UTL` part commented.

```
SQL> /
Enter value for enter_start_date: 2019-08-01
old   2:     startdate DATE := to_date('&Enter_Start_Date', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
new   2:     startdate DATE := to_date('2019-08-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
Enter value for enter_end_date: 2019-08-31
old   3:     enddate DATE   := to_date('&Enter_End_Date', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
new   3:     enddate DATE   := to_date('2019-08-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
Enter value for table1: 'A'
Enter value for table2: 'B'
Enter value for table3: 'TEST'
old   6:     var   sys.odcivarchar2list := sys.odcivarchar2list(&table1, &table2, &table3);
new   6:     var   sys.odcivarchar2list := sys.odcivarchar2list('A', 'B', 'TEST');
createdate::19-AUG-03
objectcount::3
createdate::19-AUG-07
objectcount::2
createdate::19-AUG-15
objectcount::2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply XING, I am looking like whenever I will get third prompt for table name then I need that value and want to put in excel something like  
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Entered table name'); and then data of particular table again 1 line will skip and for another table data it will append. I have shown expected ouput. Can this possible ?

Comment: @SwapnilGThaware Did you execute my code. Its doing the same. It will ask for tablename as input and then export the data to files. I emphasized on passing 3 table name at 1 time like you mentioned you wanted to pass multiple table names. Read inline comments

Comment: Yes I tried to execute your code as it is but getting error:                                 
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 6, column 56:
PLS-00357: Table,View Or Sequence reference 'MYTABLENAME' not allowed in this context
ORA-06550: line 6, column 11:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 22, column 53:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed

Comment: ORA-06550: line 22, column 53:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "VAR": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 22, column 16:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 27, column 18:
PLS-00364: loop index variable 'I' use is invalid
ORA-06550: line 25, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: @SwapnilGThaware You query is not correct and thats why you get the below issue. I somehow didnot check the query you used. `Having` clause comes after `Group by` and in your case its reverse.  Please see my updated working code.

Comment: Thanks for your time and efforts. @XING

Comment: @SwapnilGThaware Is it doing what you are trying to achieve.